# Notice: Undefined index:. PHP, передача $_GET

Tags: php, form, get

У меня есть форма, которая обрабатывается и данные которые ввёл пользователь выводятся на странице. Также есть проверка, что если поле оставлено пустым, то оно не выводится, но почему-то если некоторые поля (не все) оставить пустыми, то выдает ошибку: **Notice: Undefined index: hobbies in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 25**. И такую ошибку выдаёт не во всех пустых полях.

Код формы:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Урок "Формы": теги и их атрибуты.</h1>
    <h2>Расскажите немного о себе...</h2>
    <p id="instruction">Попробуйте создать аналогичную форму. Для целей демонстрации вполне подойдут и вымышленные</p>

        <form action="index.php" method="GET">
            <ul class="fieldsets">
                <li>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Коротко о себе</legend>
                        <ul class="info">
                            <li class="short-info-element">
                                <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" name="first-name"/>
                            </li>

                            <li class="short-info-element">
                                <label for="second-name">Фамилия:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="second-name" name="last-name"/>
                            </li>

                            <li class="short-info-element">
                                <span>Пол:</span>
                                <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male">
                                <label for="male">Мужской</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female">
                                <label for="female">Женский</label>
                            </li>

                            <li class="short-info-element">
                                <label for="age">Возраст:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="age" name="age">лет
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Подробнее о себе</legend>
                        <p>
                            <input type="radio" id="sex-male" name="sex-detailed" value="male">
                            <label for="sex-male">Молодой человек</label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="radio" id="sex-female" name="sex-detailed" value="female">
                            <label for="sex-female">Девушка</label>
                        </p>
                        <ul class="info">
                            <li>
                                <input type="date" id="birth" class="personal-info" name="birthday"/>
                                <label for="birth">Дата рождения</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="text" id="family-status" class="personal-info" name="martial-status"/>
                                <label for="family-status">Семейное положение</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="text" id="social-status" class="personal-info" name="social-status"/>
                                <label for="social-status">Социальный статус</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="text" id="place-of-living" class="personal-info" name="live-place"/>
                                <label for="place-of-living">Местожительства</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <p class="bold-text">Что вы обычно делаете на выходных:</p>
                        <ul class="info">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="sleep" name="hobbies[]" value="Sleep"/>
                                <label for="sleep">Сплю</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="friends" name="hobbies[]" value="Friends"/>
                                <label for="friends">Гуляю с друзьями</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="fishing" name="hobbies[]" value="Fishing"/>
                                <label for="fishing">Хожу на рыбалку</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="games" name="hobbies[]" value="Games"/>
                                <label for="games">Играю в игры</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="bold-text">Рассказать о формах в книге, посвященной HTML:</p>
                        <p>
                            <select id="books" name="books">
                                <option value="Book 1">Book 1</option>
                                <option value="Book 2">Book 2</option>
                                <option value="Book 3">Book 3</option>
                                <option value="Book 4">Book 4</option>
                                <option value="Book 5">Book 5</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p class="bold-text">Сколько книг вы прочитали за свою жизнь:</p>
                        <ul class="info">
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="first-option" name="quantity-of-books" value="0-10"/>
                                <label for="first-option">0-10</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="second-option" name="quantity-of-books" value="11-20"/>
                                <label for="second-option">11-20</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="third-option" name="quantity-of-books" value="21-50"/>
                                <label for="third-option">21-50</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="fourth-option" name="quantity-of-books" value="50+"/>
                                <label for="fourth-option">50+</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class="no-bottom-padding">Ваши комментарии:</span>
                        <p>
                            <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <select id="positions" name="positions[]" multiple>
                                <option value="First Position">Первая позиция</option>
                                <option value="Second Position">Вторая позиция</option>
                                <option value="Third Position">Третья позиция</option>
                                <option value="Fourth Position">Четвёртая позиция</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>И в заключении</legend>
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" id="placeholder-example" placeholder="Это поле было введено до вас"
                                   disabled>
                        </p>
                        <span class="no-bottom-padding">Email:</span>
                        <p>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                        </p>

                        <span class="no-bottom-padding">Хотите подписатья на самую модную рассылку спама?</span>
                        <p class="choose-categories">Выберите категории</p>

                        <ul class="info">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="equipment" name="categories[]" value="Equipments"/>
                                <label for="equipment">Оборудование</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="dinners" name="categories[]" value="How To Cook Dinners"/>
                                <label for="dinners">Как приготовить обеды</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="millions" name="categories[]" value="Million on 2 days"/>
                                <label for="millions">Заработай миллион за два дня!</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <p class="bold-text">На сколько сложная задача:</p>
                        <ul class="info">
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="easy" name="how-hard" value="Easy"/>
                                <label for="easy">Совсем нет</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="so-so" name="how-hard" value="So-so"/>
                                <label for="so-so">Так себе</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" id="hard" name="how-hard" value="Hard"/>
                                <label for="hard">Еле справились</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Отправить</button>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Код обработки формы:

```
<body>

<dl>
    <?php
    $first_name = $_GET["first-name"];
    $last_name = $_GET["last-name"];
    $sex = $_GET["sex"];
    $age = $_GET["age"];
    $sex_detailed = $_GET["sex-detailed"];
    $birthday = $_GET["birthday"];
    $martial_status = $_GET["martial-status"];
    $social_status = $_GET["social-status"];
    $live_place = $_GET["live-place"];
    $hobbies = $_GET["hobbies"];
    $books = $_GET["books"];
    $quantity_of_books = $_GET["quantity-of-books"];
    $comments = $_GET["comments"];
    $positions = $_GET["positions"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $categories = $_GET["categories"];
    $how_hard = $_GET["how-hard"];

     function getTextData ($variable, $label) {
        if (!empty($variable)) {
            echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
            echo '<dt>' . $label  . '</dt>';
            echo '<dd>' . $variable . '</dd>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    getTextData($first_name, "Имя:");
    getTextData($last_name, "Фамилия:");

        if (!empty($sex) && $sex == 'male') {
            echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
            echo '<dt>' . "Пол:" . '</dt>';
            echo '<dd>' . "Мужской" . '</dd>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        if (!empty($sex) && $sex == 'female') {
            echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
            echo '<dt>' . "Пол:" . '</dt>';
            echo '<dd>' . "Женский" . '</dd>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    getTextData($age, "Ваш возраст: ");

            if (!empty($sex_detailed) && $sex_detailed == 'male') {
                echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
                echo '<dt>' . "Вы:" . '</dt>';
                echo '<dd>' . "Молодой человек" . '</dd>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

            if (!empty($sex_detailed) && $sex_detailed == 'female') {
                echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
                echo '<dt>' . "Вы:" . '</dt>';
                echo '<dd>' . "Девушка" . '</dd>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

    getTextData($birthday, "Дата рождения:");
    getTextData($martial_status, "Семейное положение:");
    getTextData($social_status, "Социальный статус:");
    getTextData($live_place, "Местожительства:");

    if (!empty($hobbies)) {
        echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
        echo '<dt>' . "Ваши хобби:" . '</dt>';
        foreach ($hobbies as $hobby) {
            echo '<dd>' . $hobby . ',' . '</dd>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }

    getTextData($books, "Книга: ");
    getTextData($quantity_of_books, "Прочитано книг за свою жизнь:");
    getTextData($comments, "Ваши комментарии:");

    if (!empty($positions)) {
        echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
        echo '<dt>' . "Позиции:" . '</dt>';
        foreach ($positions as $position) {
            echo '<dd>' . $position . ',' . '</dd>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }

    getTextData($email, "Email:");

    if (!empty($categories)) {
        echo '<div class="row no-gutters">';
        echo '<dt>' . "Подписки:" . '</dt>';
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<dd>' . $category . ',' . '</dd>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }

    getTextData($how_hard, "Насколько сложная задача:");

    ?>
</dl>
</body>
```

**Вот ошибки, когда отправляешь незаполненную форму:**

Notice: Undefined index: sex in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: sex-detailed in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: hobbies in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined index: quantity-of-books in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: positions in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: categories in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: how-hard in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 32

Но если заполнить поля связанные с этими переменными, то этих ошибок нет. В чём проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Это не ошибки, а предупреждения. [Посмотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef).

Comment: @Belial предупреждения у вас потому, что нужно правильно объявлять переменные.

Comment: @entithat Спасибо, ссылка помогла. Можете добавить её в ответ. если хотите.

Comment: @Belial, да что уж там.. Приятно помочь бескорыстно:)

Comment: @entithat вы видимо ошиблись с адресатом.

Comment: @Эдуард, ой, пардон :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> если заполнить поля связанные с этими переменными, то этих ошибок нет.
>   В чём проблема?

Разве не очевидно, что когда форма не заполнена, то в `$_GET` нет данных и взять всё это богатство в виде `$_GET["first-name"]`, `$_GET["sex"]` и пр - неоткуда..

Надо проверять, что прилетел `$_GET` запрос и только если он прилетел - разбирать его, класть данные в переменные и обрабатывать.

Если очень хочется, то можно и отдельно проверять каждую переменную через **[isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)** или **[null coalesce оператор](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)** или **[empty](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)**